# Dependency Inject with Ninject 2.0

Tags: wcf, dependency-injection, ninject, wcf-client, ninject-2

A little question regarding Ninject.

I use a WCF 'duplex channel' to communicate with a service. The channel is defined as an interface, lets call it `IMyChannel` for simplicity. To instantiate a channel we use `DuplexChannelFactory<IMyChannel>` object's `CreateChannel()` method. 
So far I have manage to bind the factory class with this.

```
Bind< DuplexChannelFactory< IMyChannel>>().ToMethod(context =>
    new DuplexChannelFactory< IMyChannel>(
        new MessageEndPoint(), 
        new NetTcpBinding(),
        "net.tcp://localhost:8321")).InSingletonScope();
    }
}
```

However I'm a little unsure how to bind the `IMyChannel` interface since I use Ninject to create `DuplexChannelFactory<IMyChannel>` so to bind `IMyChannel` I do `Bind< IMyChannel>().` ???

Answer (score 1):

This isnt really an IOC container issue.

While, in theory, you could do:

```
Bind<Func<IMyInterface>>().ToConstant( context => context.Kernel.Get<DCF<IMC>>().CreateChannel)
```

and then demand a `Func<IMyInterface>()` in your ctor, calling it whenever you want to create a channel.

The problem is that the object that CreateChannel() returns implements both `IMyChannel` and `IDisposable`, hence you cannot neatly use a using block around it if that's what you're going to return. This is what the tooling generates for you when you create Service Reference, and WCF OOTB doesnt offer a general mechanism here.

I personally inject a factory, and have it have a `Create<T>()` method that yields a wrapper object that:

- implements `IDisposable`
- has a way to call methods across the channel.

It's not injectable into a post so hopefully someone will be along soon with a nice wrapper class of this nature.

Not sure if Singleton is appropriate, but I'd have to look around to be sure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Rubin.
Sry for my late respond but I got sidetracked by some other project all of the sudden. But now in back on this issue and will give your suggestion a try and report back.