# Ninject with WCF Duplex channel

Tags: c#, wcf, ninject, duplex

I'm using ninject with wcf to inject parameters into service classes. I now need to do this for a duplex service, and I'm unsure how to proceed.

At the moment, my client invokes the duplex service using a `DuplexChannelFactory` like this:

```
    InstanceContext instanceContext = new InstanceContext(new TheCallback());
    var factory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IScannerManager>(instanceContext, "ScannerManagerEndPoint");
    var channel = factory.CreateChannel();
```

IClientCallBack is part of my contract for duplex comms:

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IClientCallBack))]
public interface IScannerManager
{
    [OperationContract]
    void Register(string token);

}

public interface IClientCallBack
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void SendClientMessage(ScannerMessageWrapper message);
}
```

I've modified my service ctor to add the new param I want to inject like this:

```
    public ScannerManagerService(Func<IClientCallBack> callBack, IRepositoryFactory repositoryFactory)
    { .. }
```

Where IRepositoryFactory is what I now want to inject. I've wired up my IRepositoryFactory in my ninject bindings, but when I test the code I see:

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail] : Error activating IntPtr
No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.
Activation path:
  3) Injection of dependency IntPtr into parameter method of constructor of type Func{IClientCallBack}
  2) Injection of dependency Func{IClientCallBack} into parameter callBack of constructor of type ScannerManagerService
  1) Request for ScannerManagerService
```

So ninject is saying it can't see a binding for the callback.. I can't just define a binding for the callback I presume - is this possible with ninject?

Note: This question is similar to [Dependency Inject with Ninject 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660152/dependency-inject-with-ninject-2-0), but I'm asking it again because there are no accepted answers there. In that post the suggestion is made to inject a factory, but I'm unsure how that would look and if it would mean you don't need to use DuplexChannelFactory.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not finding anything about the `IClientCallback` class online, so I'm assuming this is something specific to your product? You can certainly create a binding to the `Func<IClientCallback>`, or you can define a specific factory interface and bind to that instead.

```
Bind<Func<IClientCallback>>.To...
```

or

```
public interface IClientCallbackFactory { IClientCallback GetCallback(); }
...
Bind<IClientCallbackFactory.To...
```

The thing is, I don't know what you'd bind it to, because I don't know what role it plays in your application.

#### Update

I did [a little reading up on Duplex Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx#Y560), and I think this may be what you're looking for:

```
Bind<Func<IClientCallback>>().ToMethod(
    c => () => OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IClientCallback>());
```

As I mentioned earlier, you could likewise create a factory interface that is implemented using the same method.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the orig. post with info about the ClientBack.. The thing is that the DuplexChannelFactory takes care of returning this, so that the client has a callback that the server can use to achieve duplex comms. I have no idea what i'd bind this to... I think it may just be easier too add another layer of abstraction so that the service just passes onto another class - which I can test easily and not have to worry about ninjecting params into my wcf duplex service.

Comment: @Matt Roberts: It's making more sense to me now. See if my update works.

Comment: Ah right, yes that seems to work :) I had to tweak your binding a little: Bind<Func<IClientCallBack>>().ToMethod(Meth); .. private static Func<IClientCallBack> Meth(IContext arg)
        {
            return () => OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IClientCallBack>();
        }

Comment: @Matt Roberts: Ah, of course, that makes sense. You probably could've also just done `.ToMethod(c => () => OperationContext.....)`